# Need help with SQL

Tags: sql

i want to choose all the LIKE values but not a specific one

Comment: There's no question here. What database, and what exactly are you trying to do? Edit and provide that info, or your question will probably be closed.

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from names where name like 'ro%' and name != 'root';
```

Will give you all ro* except root.

If you want to use multiples

```
select * from names where name like 'ro%' and name not in ('root', 'rooster');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for a LIKE query:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE NAME LIKE "John%"
```

This will return all rows which have the value "John *" in the name column.